# Extract the soil moisture for my study area and export as a GeoTIFF format

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am writing a script to extract the time series of soil moisture values from the GLDAS soil moisture data using a point shapefile in the Google Earth Engine.

However, in the results I get only 12 elements while I am looking for values from 2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31.
when I export as a GeoTIFF format is shows the error (Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.) like this.

Can someone tell me where the problem is with my code in addition to that I want to extract the soil moisture information with the date (months and years) and export it in GeoTIFF format to drive or CSV format with coordinates so that I can identify my location?

Below is the code I am working on:

(https://code.earthengine.google.com/93ed5078f10ecc5f2adbb81711021579)

```
// Create a chart for SoilMoi100_200cm_inst trend in point 1.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
          .filterBounds(point)
          .filterDate('2012-01-01', '2012-12-31')
          .select('SoilMoi100_200cm_inst');

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var start_year = 2012;
var start_date = '2012-01-01';
var end_year = 2012;
var end_date = '2012-12-31';

var years = ee.List.sequence( start_year, end_year);


var byMonthYear =  ee.FeatureCollection(
  years.map(function (y) {
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var w = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .mean();
           
      var pointMean = w.reduceRegion({reducer:ee.Reducer.first(), geometry:point,scale:25000});  
      // set the dictionary as property and cast to an ee.Image, as setMulti returns an ee.Element.
      return ee.Feature(null).set("value",pointMean.get("SoilMoi100_200cm_inst")).set("year",y).set("month",m);
      

    });
  }).flatten()
);


// print the collection, point information
print("feature collection",byMonthYear);

Export.table.toDrive({collection:byMonthYear,description:"csvExport"})

Export.image.toDrive({
image: dataset.select('SoilMoi100_200cm_inst').mean(),
description: 'smi 2012',
scale: 2500,
region: point


});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering the export part of the question. Which is unclear:

Each scene of this collection has global coverage, that's why you are getting that error.

Also, check **Export.image.toDrive** documentation:

> region (Geometry.LinearRing|Geometry.Polygon|String, optional): A
> LinearRing, Polygon, or coordinates representing region to export.
> These may be specified as the Geometry objects or coordinates
> serialized as a string.

You are providing a point as argument, so it doesn't clip the feature in the output.

Fix:

Convert your point to a polygon, something like:

```
var poly = point.buffer(10000)
```

Then clip:

```
dataset.select('SoilMoi100_200cm_inst').mean().clip(poly)
```

Or add a polygon as region.

---

For:

> However, in the results I get only 12 elements while I am looking for
> values from 2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31.

That's the output of reducing data by month:

```
var byMonthYear =  ee.FeatureCollection(
  years.map(function (y) {
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var w = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .mean();
           
      var pointMean = w.reduceRegion({reducer:ee.Reducer.first(), geometry:point,scale:25000});  
      // set the dictionary as property and cast to an ee.Image, as setMulti returns an ee.Element.
      return ee.Feature(null).set("value",pointMean.get("SoilMoi100_200cm_inst")).set("year",y).set("month",m);
      

    });
  }).flatten()
);
```

The key for getting 365 observations is filtering by day, not by month

Comment: when I am using [ var poly = point.buffer(10000) ] This code shows an error message `point.buffer is not a function` . i add my source code link https://code.earthengine.google.com/7d5a9c520c9cdb8d52fd44b810a0edf2

Comment: @MD.ASHIKUZZAMAN1705018 if you add `print(point)` before the `buffer` function, you will see that your point table does not exist.

Comment: @MD.ASHIKUZZAMAN1705018 you have defined `point`, since you're filtering and using it in the reduction. Is a geometry? What kind of object is point?

Comment: Basically i am using a area shape file.

Comment: I will try many times.but i am failed  Kindly gives me the solution.

Comment: "*gives me the solution*"? The solution is here, you just need to understand what the code does. You didn't share the assest and you think we should guess what kind of data it has *smh*

Comment: @aldo_tapia This is my source code. I cannot find out the error code.
 https://code.earthengine.google.com/0079476219be348814f34cc629ec40f0